# card's shadow on top of other cards Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview, shadow

I was wondering if there is a way to create such an effect in android where the card shadow affects other cards (appears on them) like this UI design
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09mJf.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting elevation on cards? [Material Design on Shadows](https://material.io/design/environment/light-shadows.html#shadows)